# Как преобразовать json в объект?

Tags: c#, json

Есть json, для которого Visual Studio сгенерировал вот такой класс

```
  class DB
    {
        public Result[] result { get; set; }
    }
    class Result
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string eid { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string start { get; set; }
        public string finish { get; set; }
        public string img { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string age { get; set; }

    }
```

Вот код

```
var lst = new List<Result>();
    ....
var re = new JavaScriptSerializer{ MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue, RecursionLimit = 100 }.Serialize(lst);
```

Должно получиться вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А получается вот так. То есть иерархии нет вообще

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ps вот пример json

```
{
    "result": [{
        "name": "\u0420\u043e\u0441\u0441\u0438\u044f 2",
        "id": "8798008",
        "logo": "http:\/\/1ttv.org\/uploads\/bNqW83B8A3bG2xNWCbGrRXdPF2x5gN.png",
        "description": "",
        "events": [{
            "id": "921109593",
            "eid": "e11365675650",
            "start": 1513182300,
            "finish": 1513191300,
            "title": "\u0425\u043e\u043a\u043a\u0435\u0439. \u0415\u0432\u0440\u043e\u0442\u0443\u0440. \"\u041a\u0443\u0431\u043e\u043a \u041f\u0435\u0440\u0432\u043e\u0433\u043e \u043a\u0430\u043d\u0430\u043b\u0430\". \u041f\u0440\u044f\u043c\u0430\u044f \u0442\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0441\u043b\u044f\u0446\u0438\u044f \u0438\u0437 \u041c\u043e\u0441\u043a\u0432\u044b",
            "description": "\u041d\u0430 \u043e\u0447\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0434\u043d\u043e\u043c \u044d\u0442\u0430\u043f\u0435 \u0415\u0432\u0440\u043e\u0442\u0443\u0440\u0430, \u043a\u043e\u0442\u043e\u0440\u044b\u0439 \u043f\u0440\u0438\u043d\u0438\u043c\u0430\u0435\u0442 \u0441\u0442\u043e\u043b\u0438\u0446\u0430 \u043d\u0430\u0448\u0435\u0439 \u0441\u0442\u0440\u0430\u043d\u044b, \u0432\u043f\u0435\u0440\u0432\u044b\u0435 \u0432 \u0438\u0441\u0442\u043e\u0440\u0438\u0438 \u043f\u043e\u043a\u043b\u043e\u043d\u043d\u0438\u043a\u0438 \u0445\u043e\u043a\u043a\u0435\u044f \u0443\u0432\u0438\u0434\u0438\u0442 \u0441\u0431\u043e\u0440\u043d\u0443\u044e \u042e\u0436\u043d\u043e\u0439 \u041a\u043e\u0440\u0435\u0438. \u041f\u043e\u043c\u0438\u043c\u043e \u0445\u043e\u0437\u044f\u0435\u0432 \u0431\u0443\u0434\u0443\u0449\u0438\u0445 \u041e\u043b\u0438\u043c\u043f\u0438\u0439\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0445 \u0438\u0433\u0440, \u043d\u0430 \u0440\u043e\u0441\u0441\u0438\u0439\u0441\u043a\u043e\u0439 \u0437\u0435\u043c\u043b\u0435 \u0432\u044b\u0441\u0442\u0443\u043f\u044f\u0442 \u0438 \u043a\u0430\u043d\u0430\u0434\u0446\u044b. \u041d\u0443 \u0430 \u043a\u043e\u043d\u043a\u0443\u0440\u0435\u043d\u0446\u0438\u044e \u043d\u043e\u0432\u0438\u0447\u043a\u0430\u043c \u043a\u043e\u043d\u0442\u0438\u043d\u0435\u043d\u0442\u0430\u043b\u044c\u043d\u043e\u0433\u043e \u043f\u0435\u0440\u0432\u0435\u043d\u0441\u0442\u0432\u0430 \u0441\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0430\u0432\u044f\u0442 \u0442\u0440\u0430\u0434\u0438\u0446\u0438\u043e\u043d\u043d\u044b\u0435 \u0441\u043e\u0438\u0441\u043a\u0430\u0442\u0435\u043b\u0438 \u043d\u0430\u0433\u0440\u0430\u0434 \u0438\u0437 \u0427\u0435\u0445\u0438\u0438, \u0428\u0432\u0435\u0446\u0438\u0438, \u0424\u0438\u043d\u043b\u044f\u043d\u0434\u0438\u0438, \u043f\u0440\u0438\u0435\u0437\u0436\u0430\u044e\u0449\u0435\u0439 \u0432 \u041c\u043e\u0441\u043a\u0432\u0443 \u0432 \u0440\u0430\u043d\u0433\u0435 \u043b\u0438\u0434\u0435\u0440\u0430 \u0442\u0435\u043a\u0443\u0449\u0435\u0433\u043e \u0440\u043e\u0437\u044b\u0433\u0440\u044b\u0448\u0430, \u0438, \u043a\u043e\u043d\u0435\u0447\u043d\u043e, \u0441\u0431\u043e\u0440\u043d\u043e\u0439 \u0420\u043e\u0441\u0441\u0438\u0438 \u043f\u043e\u0434 \u043f\u0440\u0435\u0434\u0432\u043e\u0434\u0438\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c\u0441\u0442\u0432\u043e\u043c \u041e\u043b\u0435\u0433\u0430 \u0417\u043d\u0430\u0440\u043a\u0430.",
            "img": "",
            "age": ""
        },
        {
            "id": "208843801",
            "eid": "e11134257882",
            "start": 1513405800,
            "finish": 1513191300,
            "title": "\"\u0421\u0438\u043b\u044c\u043d\u043e\u0435 \u0448\u043e\u0443\".",
            "description": "",
            "img": "",
            "age": ""
        }]
    },
    {
        "name": "Eurosport 1",
        "id": "6203566",
        "logo": "http:\/\/1ttv.org\/uploads\/QA9jgUaQRrE4vMno04eM3aUrklXOce.png",
        "description": "",
        "events": [{
            "id": "180327322",
            "eid": "e11720771096",
            "start": 1513189800,
            "finish": 1513193400,
            "title": "\u0424\u0443\u0442\u0431\u043e\u043b. \u041a\u0443\u0431\u043e\u043a \u0418\u0442\u0430\u043b\u0438\u0438. 1\/8 \u0444\u0438\u043d\u0430\u043b\u0430. \"\u0418\u043d\u0442\u0435\u0440\" - \"\u041f\u043e\u0440\u0434\u0435\u043d\u043e\u043d\u0435\".",
            "description": "",
            "img": "",
            "age": ""
        },
```

Comment: Из экранных снимков ничего непонятно. Это отступы так сбились или нужные квадратные/фигурные скобки отсутствуют? Вставьте, пожалуйста, содержимое желаемого и полученного файлов в текст вопроса целиком и текстом (не картинкой).

Comment: @Arhad  исправил

Comment: @tym32167 не вижу здесь дубликата

Comment: А я вижу, так как если поглядеть на мой ответ там и пройти все шаги, что я там написал, то ваш json благополучно парсится

Answer (score -3):

Надо просто добавить нужные классы. Типа

```
class Event
{
    public string start { get; set; }
    public string finish { get; set; }
    // ...
}

class Result
{
    public Event[] events { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Че заминусовали то? Ответ же верный.

Comment: ответ верный, но не забывайте о https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

Answer (score -3):

Вот такой вариант подошел

```
public class Event
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string eid { get; set; }
        public string start { get; set; }
        public string finish { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string img { get; set; }
        public string age { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string logo { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public List<Event> events { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<Result> result { get; set; }
    }
```